# Installation RGoogleAnalytics, Auth issue

Tags: r, google-analytics

When I am installing RGoogleAnalytics in R I get stuck after this below code

```
library(RGoogleAnalytics)
client.id  <- "52005287747-vskrla453am9m8r1bikq0qj9ddd3ndoo.apps.googleusercontent.com"
client.secret <- "doqIIpGXOaxgXQ23pvnITnho"

token <- Auth(client.id,client.secret)
```

And it says: **Waiting for authentication in browser...**

But no browser loads, no consent screen shows. Prior to this I've installed:

```
install.packages("RGoogleAnalytics")
```

How do I get the consent verification browser to show?